# How can I replace the semicolon with a full stop after the 'Figure' index?

Tags: floats, subfloats, figure-placement, ieeeaccess

I'm editing an overleaf paper draft following the general formats defined in the IEEE access template. The color of the overall figure indexes complies with the IEEE access template now, but the semicolon after each 'Figure' index is not right which should be replaced with a full stop. Also, the color of the indexes for the subfigure captions should be black, but they are all in 'accessblue' now. How can I set these up?

Here is my current code for the packages used:

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
%the below 5 lines of code are extra packages I referenced in addition to the original IEEE access template packages used
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{font={sf,small,stretch=0.80},labelfont={bf,color=accessblue}}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\usepackage{bm}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\DeclareMathVersion{bold}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}{T1}{times}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{NewLetters}{bold}{T1}{times}{b}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{bold}{T1}{times}{b}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{bold}{T1}{times}{b}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{bold}{T1}{times}{b}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{bold}{OT1}{pcr}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
\renewcommand\boldmath{\@nomath\boldmath\mathversion{bold}}}
\makeatother

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

%Your document starts from here ___________________________________________________
\begin{document}
\history{Date of publication 2024 00, 0000, date of current version 2024 00, 0000.}
\doi{10.1109/ACCESS.2024.1120000}
```

Here is an example with subfigures showing how I'm inserting my figures:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/subfig1.pdf}
        \caption{Description.}
        \label{fig:sub1}
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \vspace{10pt} % Adjust vertical spacing between subfigures
    
    \begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/subfig2.pdf}
        \caption{Description.}
        \label{fig:sub2}
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \caption{\textbf{Description.}}
    \label{label}
\end{figure}
```

which renders

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! While technically feasible, changing the appearance of an official IEEE template is not exactly what do you want to do.

Comment: Lose the `\captionsetup`.  Note that the caption package is not technically IEEE compatible, but there is anecdotal evidence that it will preserve the default settings if not adjusted.  You also need it for subfigures.